# What's wrong with my filter query to figure out if a key is a member of a list(db.key) property?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm having trouble retrieving a filtered list from google app engine datastore (using python for server side).  My data entity is defined as the following

```
class Course_Table(db.Model):
    course_name = db.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    ....
    head_tags_1=db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

So the head_tags_1 property is a list of keys (which are the keys to a different entity called Headings_1).

I'm in the Handler below to spin through my Course_Table entity to filter the courses that have a particular Headings_1 key as a member of the head_tags_1 property.  However, it doesn't seem like it is retrieving anything when I know there is data there to fulfill the request since it never displays the logs below when I go back to iterate through the results of my query (below).  Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
def get(self,level_num,h_key):
path = []
if level_num == "1":
    q = Course_Table.all().filter("head_tags_1 =", h_key)

    for each in q:
    logging.info('going through courses with this heading name')
    logging.info("course name filtered is %s ", each.course_name)
```

MANY MANY THANK YOUS

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I assume h_key is key of headings_1, since head_tags_1 is a list, I believe what you need is IN operator. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries</strike>

Note: your indentation inside the for loop does not seem correct.

My bad apparently '=' for list is already check membership. Using = to check membership is working for me, can you make sure h_key is really a datastore key class?

Here is my example, the first get produces result, where the 2nd one is not

```
import webapp2 from google.appengine.ext import db

class Greeting(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()
    x = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class C(db.Model):  name = db.StringProperty()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ckey = db.Key.from_path('C', 'abc')
        dkey = db.Key.from_path('C', 'def')
        ekey = db.Key.from_path('C', 'ghi')
        Greeting(author='xxx', x=[ckey, dkey]).put()
        x = Greeting.all().filter('x =',ckey).get()
        self.response.write(x and x.author or 'None')
        x = Greeting.all().filter('x =',ekey).get()
        self.response.write(x and x.author or 'None')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```